# Android change font type of Application?

Tags: android

I need font typeface **Helvetica** in my application and works for all activities.there are any source for that?

i have Helvetica.ttf file in assets folder but when i try

```
    TextView text2 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "helvetica.ttf");
    text2.setTypeface(font);
```

But error is ::

```
    10-22 17:48:43.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(951): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.logistics.typeface/com.logistics.typeface.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
10-22 17:48:43.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(951):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
10-22 17:48:43.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(951):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
10-22 17:48:43.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(951):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
10-22 17:48:43.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(951):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
10-22 17:48:43.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(951):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-22 17:48:43.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(951):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-22 17:48:43.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(951):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-22 17:48:43.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(951):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 17:48:43.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(951):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-22 17:48:43.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(951):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-22 17:48:43.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(951):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-22 17:48:43.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(951):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-22 17:48:43.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(951): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
10-22 17:48:43.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(951):     at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:147)
10-22 17:48:43.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(951):     at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:121)
10-22 17:48:43.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(951):     at com.logistics.typeface.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
10-22 17:48:43.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(951):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-22 17:48:43.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(951):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
10-22 17:48:43.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(951):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: can you be more clear. Do you want to change the font type based on user input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need font typeface Helvetica in my application

I hope you have properly licensed this for distribution, as Helvetica [appears to be a commercial font](http://www.linotype.com/526/helvetica-family.html).

> and works for all activities

By you manually bundling the font in your app and by manually applying it to each and every `TextView` (or subclass), yes.

Comment: @user1003730: Not all TTF files are supported by Android for some reason. It does not like yours.

Comment: OMG....its works fine...Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(),"Helvetica.ttf");

Answer (score 6):

Define font style in resources and use where ever you are creating your elements.
Like this:

```
<style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
</style>
```

You may refer to these links as well:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-themes-in-android-applications.html

If you want to use custom font then have a look at this :

http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/05/android-development-using-custom-fonts/

Comment: ,this is only for one item .there are any way to for all item in once?