# Change FontFace of application

Tags: android, textview, android-fonts

I have one application in Which I want to change font of text in whole application. 

Is there anyway to change font of application **Programmatically** or with **xml in manifest**.?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858860/android-change-font-type-of-application and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404820/how-to-set-default-font-family-for-entire-android-app

Comment: i believe this has been answered n number of time. please go through the forum.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

1.place your ttf file in assets folder and add these lines to your java file

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(),"fonts/androidnation.ttf");

tv.setTypeface(font);
```

2.To set it through xml

[XML Typeface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128331/how-to-change-fontfamily-of-textview-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is creating your own TextView:

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {

    public DMTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
      // you need your TypefaceFile "myTypeface.ttf" in the assets folder of your project
      setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"myTypeface.ttf"));
    }

    // add the other constructors if you want
}
```

now, you can use it anywhere in your xml:
`<com.your.package.MyTextView ... >` just like normal textviews

It might be improved by caching the Typeface, so you don't have to create it again with every Reference to your TextView.

Comment: really kind to downvote an answer and don't tell why. How am I supposed to know what I was doing wrong for two years (and was always working fine) if you don't tell me?! Thanks a lot, little minds.

Answer (score 0):

Place you fonts in fonts folder and then use the following code.

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.appname);
Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/epimodem.ttf");
tv.setTypeface(face);
```

This is the way to set font programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Create **fonts** folder in asset and paste the fonts whatever you want to paste.

Create one class. Name it **Typesafe.java**

```
public enum TypeSafe {
   HELVETICANEUELTCOMBD,
   HELVETICANEUELTCOMBDCN,
   HELVETICANEUELTCOMCN,
}
```

After that create one method in your `Activity` or if you have the `Utility` class.

```
public void setTypeface(TextView textView, TypeSafe type, AssetManager assetManager){
    if (TypeSafe.HELVETICANEUELTCOMBD.equals(type)) {
        final Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(assetManager, "fonts/HelveticaNeueLTCom-Bd.ttf");
        textView.setTypeface(typeface);
    } else if (TypeSafe.HELVETICANEUELTCOMBDCN.equals(type)) {
        final Typeface typeface1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(assetManager, "fonts/HelveticaNeueLTCom-BdCn.ttf");
        textView.setTypeface(typeface1);
    } 
}
```

Call these method in your `activity`.

```
setTypeface(yourtextView, TypeSafe.HELVETICANEUELTCOMLT, getAssets());
```